# How to make my post to be seen by only some friends?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have facebook ids of some of my friends. I want to post on my newsfeed,by using facebook graph api.

How can I make only these friends(facebook ids I have) to see my post?

Did I need to create any group for this?

Comment: I think you will need group id for this... Does facebook has selective sharing option like Google+ ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/privacy-parameter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  In the parameter bundle, add a privacy field. see example below:

```
public String postToWall() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "test message");
    JSONObject privacy = new JSONObject();
    privacy.put("value", "CUSTOM");
    privacy.put("friends", "SOME_FRIENDS");
    privacy.put("allow", "FRIEND_ID_1,FRIEND_ID_2...");
    params.putString("privacy", privacy.toString());

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook(YOUR_APP_ID);
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFacebookRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncFacebookRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new BaseRequestListener() {
       ...
    });
```

Comment: How can I do this with graph api

Comment: the android sdk uses the graph API, if you follow the example code above, it will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

A post by its definition can be seen by everybody.

Alternatively you can

1. Post to a pre-created group
2. Message a group of friends

Comment: How to create a custom list(so that  only these people can see this post),how can I do this using graph api